# mysql insert from list with multiple submit buttons

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an HTML table with PHP loop and hidden fields and when a user chooses an item from the list and presses the submit button, I want that item data inserted into a DB. The problem is when the button is pressed, it always inserts the same data fromt the last row of the list.

```
<form id="paymentForm" role="form" action="<?php echo base_url('payment/save'); ?>" method="post">
<?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
<td><input type="hidden" name="sum" value="<?php echo $row['sum']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php echo $row['total']; ?>" /></td>
<td><a href="#" onclick="document.forms['paymentForm'].submit();">Save</a></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

I am also using standart code for insertion:
$query="INSERT INTO info (sum, total) VALUES ($sum, $total)";

Comment: You mean you have a `form` tag wrapping a table with multiple `input` elements, all with the same name? And an anchor tag with inline javascript submitted said form? This should be obvious why you're getting the result you're getting. If you want just the one row submitted, put the `form` element in the last `td` with a `<button type='submit'>Save</button`, then move the `input type='hidden'` elements into the same `td` within the form. That way you're submitting the form with only one set of `input`s and you can style the `button` to look like your `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

When you press that "Save" button, you are submitting the form in its entirety. There is no distinction to which information you've selected. Only the *last instance* of `sum` and `value` will be passed to the server as a header. Meaning, the last row of your table is the only one that will ever be saved.

I've written an example form in JSFiddle, which shows how to have many rows submitting back individual values when their save button is pressed.

http://jsfiddle.net/w6nug118/3/

To summarize the code, my form works by having *only* one instance of `sum` and `total`. The button changes these values to what their `data-` attributes are before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you will either need to use multiple form tags and tell the button to submit (this) form... or you can use Ajax to post just the two inputs above the button that is clicked.  Something along those lines:

```
<?php $counter = 1; ?>
<?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
    <td>
        <form id="paymentForm<?=$counter;?>" role="form" action="<?php echo base_url('payment/save'); ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="sum" value="<?php echo $row['sum']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php echo $row['total']; ?>" />
        <a href="#" onclick="document.forms['paymentForm<?=$counter;?>'].submit();">Save</a>
        </form>
    </td>
<?php 
    $counter++;
  endforeach; 

?>
```

Comment: `form` tags are illegal wrapped around `td` elements.